# How to make a copy safe container with std::list iterators stored in a std vector in c++?

Tags: c++, list, vector, std, deep-copy

For my GUI i need a class with the following purposes to manage controls (windows, buttons etc)

- random access to the elements by `[index]`
- random access to the elements by `["key"]`
- pointer stability, so `ptr=&container[index]` wont change if elements are added or erased
- copy safety. All elements must by stored in the container and copied if '=' is used like `container2=conatiner1` (deep-copy)
- the order of the elements in the list must be changeable, yet the pointers to the elements must remain valid. If `ptr1=container[1]` and `ptr2=container[2]`, then after swapping the order of 1 and 2, `ptr1==container[2]` and `ptr2==container[1]`

I came to the conclusion that std::list provides the stability for the pointers that I need and std::vector the random access. So I have the idea to store a tuple of std string and iterator in a vector. However, the iterators are all invalid after the container is copied.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem best?

Here the main code of the current approach (only important parts are included):

```
template < class T >
class ControlList 
{
    struct Tuple{std::string first;typename std::list<T>::iterator second;};
    std::vector<Tuple> list;
    std::list<T> objects;

    inline T& operator [](int i)
    {
        return *list[i].second;
    }
    inline T& operator [](std::string s)
    {
        loopi(0,vlist.size()) 
        if(s==vlist[i].first) 
            return *vlist[i].second;
    }
}
```

The string access is slow, but usually the container has not more than 10 elements and its used rarely in the program.

**Update:**

The shared pointer is already good, but cannot solve for the deep copy I need. Lets say I have window2=window1. Now if I have a shared pointer, then pushing a button in window2 also pushes the same button in window1, which is not wanted. I really need a new instance of all objects contained in the container.

Is it possible to override the copy constructor to create new instances of the objects referenced by the smart pointers ?

Both, windows and buttons are stored in a `ControlList` , where a window contains multiple lists.

**Update2:**

Overriding the copy constructor and the assignment constructor has apparently solved the problem

**Update3:**

I just released the GUI this class was intended for under MIT.

[Download here.](http://voxels.blogspot.com/2015/07/opengl-game-gui-widgets-with-source.html)

Comment: Is this C++11 or C++03?

Comment: You should have a single container with modelling the most general requirements (that is a std::vector to handles of GUI-elements) and views into that container (std::vector::iterator)

Comment: Out of curiosity, you say that "The string access is slow", what is slow, and how important is its speed? (You said it isn't used often, but is it used in time critical moments? ) This could potentially affect the proposed solution.

Comment: @Rootix This is mostly a string and argument optimization--you could probably use a reference for the argument or perhaps see if the comparison algorithm is completely optimized.

Comment: @VermillionAzure: Or C++14

Comment: You can achieve pointer stability and the swapping behavior by using a vector of shared_ptr

Comment: @VermillionAzure ok, wasn't sure what to suggest in regards to the pointer problem as that depends on version of C++, but from what it shows, it doesn't appear to be the best optimized string search algorithm. (I could very likely be mistaken however.) As the OP mentioned it was slow, I wasn't sure if that was something he was wanting advice on, or merely for fixing the pointers.

Answer (score 3):

If you were to use `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::unique_ptr<T>>>`, you could copy the items however you wanted to, and the resulting value would just require one more step of indirection to access. This would eliminate much of the complexity you have right now with 3 different structures. As a bonus, the items would also automatically cleanup after itself.

If you require owner-observer semantics with the pointers, you could instead opt for `std::shared_ptr<T>` and `std::weak_ptr<T>`. Shared pointers can easily create weak pointers, which act as non-owning observers which do not affect the referencing counting of the shared pointer.

**Edit:** Just to add on, `shared_ptr` and the other smart pointers are C++11 and later-exlcusive. If you desire C++03-compatible solutions, you can look to past Boost implementations or perhaps create one yourself by observing the C++11/14 spec.

***Edit2:*** Here is some code to assist:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9bf52e5428a48af

```
#include <vector>  //vector
#include <memory>  //smart pointers
#include <utility> //pair
#include <string>  //string
#include <iostream>//cout

template <class T>
class Container {
public:
    inline void push(const std::string& s, const T& t) {
        objects.push_back(std::pair<std::string, std::shared_ptr<T>>(s, std::make_shared<T>(t)));   
    }

    inline T& operator [](const size_t& i)
    {
        return *(objects[i]->second);
    }
    inline T& operator [](const std::string& s)
    {
        for (auto it : objects) {
            if(s == it.first) { 
                return *(it.second);
            }
        }

        //welp, what do you do here if you can't find it?
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::shared_ptr<T>>> objects;
};

int main() {
    Container<int> cont;
    std::string str {"hi"};
    int i {2};

    cont.push(str, i);

    //This is good...
    std::cout << cont["hi"] << std::endl;

    //But undefined behavior!
    std::cout << cont["02"] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I have adopted your code and replaced my old std:vector<Tuple> class, with struct Tuple { std::string first, T second;}. Unfortunately was the entire window system messed up afterwards, and the framerate dropped to 1/10th. I will add details in the original question

Comment: Now it works :) Seems it was a bug on my side. Thx again!

Comment: Actually after further testing, the shared pointer does not exactly what I intended. After testing it turned out that container2=container1 does not create a deep copy, but just copys the pointers. This means that window2=window1 does not create new instances of the controls, which is a problem. Using a slider in window2 also modifies a slider in window1 then

Comment: @MarcoPolo you'd just have to write a certain part to ensure a deep copy on assignment or placement, I guess.